# JQM listview based on category

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I`m stuck. I need to set listview  autodivider based on category. Tried to use example from documentation. It shows only the category of the first li. Please help.

```
for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {

            item = dataset.item(i);
            allVendors.push('<li category="' + item['usercat'] +'"><a href="" data-view-id="' + item['id'] +'" class="view"><h2>' + item['username'] + '</h2></a></li>');               
        }
            // Remove any previously appended
            $('.todo-listview li').remove();

            // Append built up arrays to ULs here.
            $('.todo-listview').append(allVendors);            

            $('.todo-listview').listview({
                autodividers:true,
                autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
                var out = $("li").attr("category"); /* generate a string based on the content of li */;
                return out;
                }

                });
            $('.todo-listview').listview("refresh");
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle depicting the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, autodividers really only works if your dataset is already sorted by category. Assuming it is, try using a data attribute for category just like your view-id:

```
<li data-category="' + item['usercat'] +'">
```

Then in your autodividersSelector script, simply retrieve this data attribute:

```
$('.todo-listview').listview({
      autodividers:true,
      autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
        var out = li.data("category");
        return out;
      }
});
```

In the autodividersSelector function, li is already a jQuery object representing the `<li>` dom element, so just use the jQuery .data() function to retrieve the category.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6zdcg5co/3/)**